# PHP Error while outputing in real time

Tags: php, flush

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
echo 'Begin ...<br />';
ob_start();
for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
{
    echo $i . '<br />';
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
```

why these code is not output $i each second?
it output on 10 second later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your code is, indeed, outputing $i in every 1 second steadily when ran from the terminal but it doesn't do it when load through web.

The workaround for you is to enable implicit flushing: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php

And remove that `ob_start()` call. The following code works perfectly:

```
<?php
    header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
    echo 'Begin ...<br />';
    ob_implicit_flush (1);
    for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
    {
        echo $i . '<br />';
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, thought it still no any effect.

Comment: look like it is my enviourment problem. i using http://www.phpstudy.net/phpstudy/phpStudy.zip , it is an all in one php enviourment for windows.  if using WampServer2.1a-x32.exe these code will works perfectly, might some extension problem or vc problem.  by the way, do you know any forums or blog or any website for php study?

Comment: this is works, but not perfectly. given Notice: ob_flush(): failed to flush buffer. if "@ob_flush, then cant working.""\n" header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
    echo 'Begin ...<br />';
    // ob_start();
    ob_end_flush();

    ob_implicit_flush(1);
    for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ )
    {
        echo $i . "\n";
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        sleep(1);
    }